# what is the maximal domain of $x^x$ function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

consider the function $f$:$A\rightarrow\mathbb R$,    $f(x)=x^x$

were $A\subseteq\mathbb R$

clearly for $x>0$ the function is defined

but for $x=-{1\over 2n}$ where $n\in\mathbb N$

$f(x)=(-{1\over 2n})^{-{1\over 2n}}={1\over (-{1\over 2n})^{{1\over 2n}}}$ 
not in $\mathbb R$

so $-{1\over 2n}\notin A$ for any  $n\in\mathbb N$

my problem is what is the maximal set we can consider as $A$

is $A=\mathbb R\setminus$ {${-{1\over 2n}}|n\in\mathbb N$} ?

Answer (score 0):

For negative $x$, you need $x$ to be a rational number with odd denominator (in lowest terms).

Comment: For $x^x$ where $x<0$ irrational, you normally get complex (non-real) values.  But might there not be some exceptional negative irrational $x$ where at least one value of $x^x$ is real?